# How to solve FileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry error on gradle build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, build.gradle

After instal in another computer the android studio, and then create the libgdx project, when i run the project, the graidle build failed with this erro:

**Error:Could not create service of type FileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry using TaskExecutionServices.createFileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry().

> Could not create service of type CachingFileHasher using TaskExecutionServices.createFileSnapshotter().**

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: what gradle version are you using? would you mind raising a bug report at discuss.gradle.org if that error persists?

Comment: I am using gradle:2.3.3, Facing same issue.

Comment: This happened to me a few times when another app was accessing the project files. Specifically a backup app was storing them. I closed it and deleted the .gradle folder. Then I rebuilt the project and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on a Jenkins job i'm trying to run. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `build` folder (`$buildDir`) and run the project again. Sometimes it might be as a result of permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when debugging and executing the Gradle build at the same time.

The reason is that the `/build` folder (output directory or `$buildDir`) is locked by the debugging process, so stopping it will be OK.